# How to verify Restful Client certificate authentication working with WCF?

Tags: wcf, x509certificate, fiddler

I have set up Restful webservice in WCF  with client authentication using certificate authentication. I am also using SSL (on IIS) for Rest services. When I use fiddler to check whether SSL and certificate authentication are working then I can find only one request of http which is returning SSL encrypted data. But what I am looking for is verifying my certificate authentication is actually working or not.

For testing purpose what I have done so far is 
1) removing certificate from client request and getting **Forbidden** error message from WCF service 
2) also sending invalid certificate name and getting again **Forbidden** error message from WCF service.

Kindly tell me how can I check certificate handshake for authentication using Fiddler or any other tool .